# FadeIn() is not applying to my code

Tags: jquery

Here is my code.. i want apply fade i did it like below but fade is not applying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       var i = 1;

       $('#accLink').click( function(){

          if(i<=3){
             $('#accCnt').append('<div>hello Testing</div>').fadeIn(100);
          }

          i = i+1

       });
    });
    </script>
    <body>
       <div class="accordion"> <a href="#" id="accLink" class="accHd">Home</a>
          <div id="accCnt"> Div Content 1<br>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
             tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I thnk initially you will need to set the style of the div you are fading in to visibiility:hidden, display:none, or use jquery hide() before the fadeIn function

Comment: S ur right m using same way thanku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code appends the new div and then tries to fade in `#accCnt` - which isn't going to work because, of course, that's already visible. Place your new div in a jQuery collection (`$()`) and then call `fadeIn()` on that instead.

Try something like this:

```
$('#accCnt').append($('<div>hello Testing</div>').fadeIn(100));
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dBp5j/)

Comment: Its Works.. Thanks for explanations and help

Comment: @Nafeez Glad to have helped, please remember to accept the answer that solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fade your new created div you better use this syntax:

```
$('<div>hello Testing</div>').hide().appendTo('#accCnt').fadeIn(100);
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sP84T/)

Comment: Ya i guess this is a gud way.. its working in my code as well thanku